# Doing necessary work before member initialization in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I've got a design question concerning classes and their constructors in C++. I'm coming from several years of Java experience. In Java, I would do things like this: I've got a class to manage an SQLite DB as a storage backend. In the constructor of this class, I would hand over the path to the applications data directory as a parameter. Then, I would look for the database file, instatiate a connection, and for example load the most current entry of a table for the purpose of caching.

My Problem now is how to do this in C++. My main problem here is that when execution reaches the first statement of the constructor, all class members were already initialized, either implicitly or explicitly.

My question now is: If I had some computations to do on the constructor parameters before using them to initialize the class members, how would I do that in C++?

I've already found that I can simply use assignment to the members in the constructors, but I've also read you should not do that, because it would mean that the members are first initialized with their default constructors, and then initialized again.

What is the canonical way when you have some computation to do (e.g. loading and parsing a configuration file) before class members can be initialized? I would prefer to simply give a path to the constructor, and then do the loading and parsing an member initialization with the loaded values inside the constructor.

Comment: Look up member initializer list.

Comment: initializing members in the constructor before you use them is perfectly fine and it's done all the time; the default constructor does not really belong in this sentence since you are overiding it

Comment: @0x499602D2 "My main problem here is that when execution reaches the first statement of the constructor, all class members were already initialized, either implicitly or explicitly." - looks like the author of the question already did that

Comment: I already have. The member initializer list is my problem. I would need to do some things (like I said, loading config files for example) with the constructor parameters before member initialization. The member initializer list doesn't help with that. (I'm not talking about some simple arithmetic on the constructor parameters)

Comment: Your class might violate the single responsibility principle. I.e. it might be better to separate the caching from the management of the database resource. If you do this, the problem might simply disappear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the computation part in separate function:

```
class C {
  std::string x;
  int y;
  C(int xarg, int yarg);
};

std::string computeX(int xarg, int yarg) {
    ...
  return result;
}

C::C(int xarg, int yarg) : x(computeX(xarg, yarg)), y(yarg) {}
```

As the "initialisation" function you may use a global function, a function defined locally in the source file (e.g. in unnamed namespace), or even invoke a lambda defined in place. You can also use a static member function - also if it is private - or a member function of one of the arguments.

Comment: OP: If you wanted to hide the detail of this function, you can make it a private static member of the class, too.

Comment: @cdhowie Good suggestion, I will add it to the answer

Comment: Hm, I've been thinking about something similar to this. First, I like this solution, but it is somewhat unfit for what I've got in mind: Loading a configuration file and initializing the members from the resulting struct, for example. What I had thought of is this: Have a class member holding the results of parsing the configuration file, and initialize it before all the other members, then use it in the initializer list of the constructor to initialize the remaining members. But that does feel somewhat hacky.

Comment: @MichaelMeier it is indeed hacky, since it introduces additional state. Also, it wouldn't work in multithreaded case. If you use C++11 you may declare additional private constructor accepting the structure as parameter, and use delegating constructors.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka What about that technique would break in the presence of other threads?

Comment: @WojtekSurowka Excellent, I hadn't thought about delegating constructors, it seems to be the best solution. Have a public constructor taking the config file path and calling a private constructor which takes the resulting struct as parameter and initializes the class members. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MichaelMeier The target ctor in ctor delegation intializes all bases and members. Any ctor body is still only executed after executing the mem-initializer-list.

Comment: @dyp Yes, I've realized this. But it nevertheless solves my problem: I can now have a delegating constructor taking the config file path, and delegating to the target constructor with the result of a method call returning a struct containing the parsed config file in the initializer list. Then, in the target constructor, I can use the elements of the struct parameter to initialize the member variables in the initializer list. No consturctor bodies are required for either constructor.

Comment: @cdhowie Using static member to temporarily store the results of a computation is not thread safe, since the static member may be overwritten by another thread before use.

Comment: @WojtekSurowka I don't think Michael indicated that the data member was static... I was envisioning what he said as `a_class::a_class(std::string const & filename) : config(filename), a(config.a), b(config.b) ...`

Comment: @cdhowie I understood "class member" as static data member. Now I see I could misunderstood. Anyway the solution with delegating constructors is much better.